# Could not get unknown property 'flutterRoot' for project ':app'

Tags: android, flutter

**Error message:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\my_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 22
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'flutterRoot' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

```
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter    
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk    
flutter.buildMode=debug    
flutter.versionName=1.0.0    
flutter.versionCode=1
```

Comment: You can see my solution at the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/77166753/20137398